# FLASK and WTForms | TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I've trying to learn Flask to create an app that take some body measurements and returns body parameters as Body Mass Index or Body Fat Percentage. The problem is that I'm using wtform to create the forms, and when I try to use it, data come as NoneType and throws this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

**Flask Code**

```py
from flask import Flask, url_for, render_template, make_response, request, redirect, session
from forms import DecimalField, BooleanField 
import body_calculator  



app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static',template_folder='templates')

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def index():
    
    form = DecimalField()
    
    sex = request.form.get('sex')
    age = request.form.get('age')
    height = request.form.get('height')
    weight = request.form.get('weight')
    waist = request.form.get('waist')
    
    body = body_calculator.Parameters(height, weight, age, sex, waist)

    LBM = body.Body_Lean_Mass()
    BMR = body.Basal_Metabolic_Rate()
    BFP = body.Body_Fat_Percentage()
    BMI = body.Body_Mass_Index()

        
    context = {
        'int_form' : form,
        'LBM' : LBM,
        'BMR' : BMR,
        'BMI' : BMI
        }
    
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        return render_template('index.html', **context)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**Calculator Code**

```
BMI = None

class Parameters:

    def __init__(self, height, weight, age, sex, waist):
        self.height = height
        self.weight = weight
        self.age = age
        self.sex = sex
        self.waist = waist
    

# Body Lean Mass function
def Body_Lean_Mass(self):
    if self.sex == 0: 
        BLM = (0.3281 * self.weight) + (0.33929 * self.height) - 29.5336
        return round(BLM,2) 
    
    if self.sex == 1:
        BLM = (0.29569 * self.weight) + (0.41813 * self.height) - 43.2933
        return round(BLM,2) 
    
# Body Mass Index function
def Body_Mass_Index(self):
    
    global BMI
    BMI = self.weight / (self.height / 100) **2 
    return round(BMI,2)


# Body Fat Percentage 
def Body_Fat_Percentage(self):
    
    if self.sex == 0:
        BFP = 1.20 * BMI + 0.23 * self.age - 16.2
        if self.age <= 15:
            BFP = 1.51 * BMI - 0.70 * self.age - 2.2
        return round(BFP,2) 
    
    
    if self.sex == 1:
        BFP = 1.20 * BMI + 0.23 * self.age - 5.4
        if self.age <= 15:
            BFP = 1.51 * BMI - 0.70 * self.age + 1.4
        return round(BFP,2) 

    
# Basal Metabolic Rate
def Basal_Metabolic_Rate (self): 
    s = 0
    
    if self.sex == 0:
        s =+ 5
    if self.sex == 1:
        s =- 161
    
    BMR = (self.weight * 10 ) + (self.height * 6.25) - (self.age * 5) + s 
    return round(BMR,2) 
``
```

Comment: Either weight or age is `None`. Check your inputs.

Comment: Hey! Could you please provide your `forms.py` and the HTML used to display the chart?

Comment: You've just called your form `DecimalField()`. This is a field type in a WTForm, and you haven't attached a value to it, so it will have adverse effects in the browser.

Comment: I gonna make another post with more information and showing you guys what's happening now in the code.